# Getting TeamCity notify using Google Talk

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0, google-talk

I'm setting up TeamCity 7.0.3 on a build machine. Everything is working OK apart from the Google Talk notifications using the Jabber notifier. When I send a test notification it works fine. But when the build completes/fails I don't get any notifications. The notifications do work locally on the machine using the system tray notifier. I have registered for all projects and all events but stil nothing is coming through. I am using the same gmail account to send the message as to receive it which could be a bit odd but the test messages work. This could be a firewall issue I guess but again the test message works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following settings in TeamCity 7.1 to set up Jabber:

http://i48.tinypic.com/9ay0xz.png

Obviously, replace my_user@gmail.com with the Google Talk user that should send notifications. **Note that, when using Google Talk, you can't send messages to yourself, so the Server User must be different than the Jabber accounts for any users that want to receive notifications.**

Now, you need to configure the notification rules for your user. Click on your name in the upper right hand corner, then in "My Settings & Tools" click "Edit" beside the Jabber Notifier under "Watched Builds and Notifications". This page looks like this:

http://i47.tinypic.com/xpq3y9.png

Note that the "Jabber Account" must be different than the "Server User" above (or else you won't receive notifications; this is the first mistake I made when first setting this up). Also note that you must set up rules for each build or groups of builds that you want Jabber notifications for by clicking "Add new rule." Jabber Notifier will not inherit your Email Notifier rules (this is the other mistake I made when first setting this up).

Comment: Using a different account to send and receive worked. Oddly though I no longer get the test message in the sending account. But its all working well now thanks.